# How to implement inner corner radius in triangle in react-native

Tags: react-native

[image: I have a design like this]

I have tried all possible ways to implement an inner border radius but I can't implement this. Have you anyone know about this.

I have referred [this](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/The-Shapes-of-React-Native) but I can't draw this layout.

Comment: Take a look at this [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg#supported-elements)

Comment: Instead of trying to set a border on the shape, it can also work to render two triangles, one of top of the other, and position the smaller one so that it looks like a border.

Comment: If I am using 2 Triangles but I must be apply color for both otherwise they not showing properly. Can you share example for this because I must be set transparent other part in triangle.

Comment: react-native-svg not implement this layout. Have you idea about inner border readies like I have share image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you can achive this using 2 methods

1. stacking the views
2. using svg

working example: https://snack.expo.io/@ashwith00/honest-peach

code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Svg, Path } from 'react-native-svg';

const RADVALUE = 40;
const SIZE = 200;
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.traingleCorner}>
        <View style={styles.coloredPart} />
        <View style={styles.uncoloredPart} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.traingleCorner}>
        <Svg
          width={`${SIZE}`}
          height={`${SIZE}`}
          fill="red"
          strokeWidth={1}
          viewBox={`0 0 ${SIZE} ${SIZE}`}>
          <Path
            d={`M0 0L0 ${SIZE}L${SIZE} ${SIZE}Q${RADVALUE} ${
              SIZE - RADVALUE
            } 0 0 `}
          />
        </Svg>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  traingleCorner: {
    width: SIZE,
    height: SIZE,
  },
  coloredPart: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  uncoloredPart: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: SIZE,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

In svg just change SIZE, RADVALUE as your requirements

Comment: SVG is working perfect. In view facing issue for color. I must be need to transparent color.

Comment: Then its better to use svg u won't be able to get that kind of curve using views